# how to change flags manually (in assembly code) for 8086?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, flags

Is there any way to change every flag manually? Or do you have to use a command with a result that you know will change them?

Basically I'm working with the command `RCL`, and I don't want to get 1 at the begining, so I want to change the **CF** to 0, and I know that I can use commands like:

```
mov al, 0
shl al, 1
```

But I want to know if there is any other way to do that, without the use of another commands result.

I would also want to know whether the way you may show me, can also be used to change **all** of the flags, not only CF, but OF, ZF, and so on.

Comment: Maybe sahf / popf?

Comment: Carry has dedicated instructions (in answer), but if you are lucky, sometimes you just can reorder your code, for example if you would happen to do some and/or/xor ahead of rcr, it would make CF=0 too. Part of assembly "golfing" is to order your instruction in such way that even by-products are reused - when possible. But such code is harder to read and understand, so `clc` is perfect fit for you. If you have a need to change flag (RCL is a valid need), then it's very likely the CPU has some way, the instruction set as whole is nicely working together (although sometimes it's not obvious).

Comment: Actually that is a pretty nice way to solve this problem, but if i want to set the flags, it will be a problem, but i will definitely use the clc command its a lot easier for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any instruction that treat `eflags` as read-write GP-register.
Quoting Intel<sup>1</sup>:

> Some of the flags in the EFLAGS register can be modified directly, using special-purpose instructions (described in
>   the following sections). **There are no instructions that allow the whole register to be examined or modified directly**.
>   The following instructions can be used to move groups of flags to and from the procedure stack or the EAX register:
>   LAHF, SAHF, PUSHF, PUSHFD, POPF, and POPFD. After the contents of the EFLAGS register have been transferred to
>   the procedure stack or EAX register, the flags can be examined and modified using the processor’s bit manipulation
>   instructions (BT, BTS, BTR, and BTC).

The `eflags` register is divided into three groups: *Status flags*, *Control flags* and *System flags*.

[image: eflags content]

Of the *Status flags* only the *CF* can be manipulated directly with `clc`, `stc`, `cmc`.
There is no instruction to read the *CF* but you can read it indirectly with instructions like `cmovcc`, `adc`, `setcc`. 
All other flags need to be modified with specially tailored arithmetic instructions or by coping the *Status group* content of `eflags` into `ah` (with `lahf`) or the stack (with `pushfd`) and than back into `eflags` (with `sahf` or `popfd`).

In the *Control flags* group there is only *DF* that can be manipulated with `cld` and `std`.
To read the current value of `DF` you need to use `pushfd`.

The *System flags* are usually manipulated indirectly by performing some privileged operation like switching a task, entering v86 mode and similar.
The *IF* can be manipulated directly with `cli` and `sti`.
All other flags can only be manipulated with `pushfd`/`popfd`.

---

For reference:

- In 64-bit mode the flag register is `rflags` but the higher 32 bits are reserved so far, thereby `rflags` is handled as `eflags`.
- `pushfd` pushes `eflags` on the stack. There is also a 16-bit version `pushf` that pushes only the lower 16 bits of `eflags`. Same for `popfd`/`popf`.
- `lahf`/`sahf` only copies the status flags.

---

<sup>1</sup> Intel Manuals, Volume 1, Section 3.4.3.