# VMWare Workstation and x86 platform

Tags: x86, vmware, x86-emulation

I'm studying virtualization from the Tanenbaum's book ("Modern Operating Systems"). I have clearly in my mind all the basic concept of the virtualization, but i can't understand better how VMWare Workstation works.

First, the VMWare Workstation has two components:

- VMM: it cares about the instruction execution.
- VMX: interfaces the VMM with the host OS.

The VMM uses before each (?) execution a "decision algorithm" to establish if can execute it using the "Direct Execution" (trap-and-emulate) or the "Binary Translation".

Tanenbaum said that a sensible-instruction generates a "trap" only in several cases (in this case the VMM can use the Direct Execution, improving the performance).

What isn't clear for me, is why on the x86 platform a sensible instruction, isn't sensible all the time (on the x86 platform), and in how circumstances that is true?

Comment: In what a "virtualization-sensible" instruction differ from a sensible instruction? And what is "server case"? Are you just referring about hardware-assisted virtualization (that "only" powerful servers should have)?

Comment: @denish I've rolled back your edit because it was incorrect. [Inline code formatting should be used only for things that are *actually* code, not just to add emphasis.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/inline-code-spans-should-not-be-used-for-emphasis-right) For emphasis, use bold or italics.

Comment: There is no difference between virtualizable instruction and sensible instruction. Second it's several cases not "server case". I'm sorry for this mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I haven't read the Tanenbaum's book, this is my interpretation of the author words.**

---

The 18 sensitive instructions, according to Wikipedia, that cannot be run directly are:

> `sgdt` (Read the GDT of the host, not of the guest)
>   `sidt` (As above, but for the IDT)
>   `sldt` (As above, but for the LDT)
>   `smsw` (Read the control register 0 of the host, not the guest one)
>   `pushf` (Read the flags, particularly [system flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39816491/change-flags-manually-assembly-8086/39816897#39816897), of the host, not of the guest)
>   `popf` (As above, but write, only some, of the flags)
>   `lar` (Read the access right from the descriptors tables of the host, not of the guest)
>   `lsl` (Read the segment limit from the descriptors tables of the host, not of the guest)
>   `verr`, `verw` (Check for read/write access using the host descriptors tables, not the guest ones)
>   `pop`/`push` (Use the host segment descriptors for the size of the operands and the stack pointer)
>   `call FAR`, `jump FAR`, `int`, `retf` (Transfer control according to the host descriptors tables)
>   `str` (Set the task register of the host)
>   `mov <segment registers>` (use the host descriptors tables, not the guests ones)

<sup><sub>The rationales behind the sensitivity is a work of mine</sub></sup>

None of this instruction trap always.

Some, not counting memory access exceptions, never do:  `pushf`, `popf`, `lar`, `lsl`, `verr`, `verw`, `push`, `pop`.

Some trap only if the host has configured them to do so: `smsw`, `sgdt`, `sidt`, `sldt`, `str`.
This is likely to not be what Tanenbaum intended to say though.

Some trap almost certainly but some values can make them work: `call FAR`, `jmp FAR`, `retf`, `int`.
This is probably what Tanenbaum meant.

Put in simple words, an instruction like `jmp FAR 08h:00h` is trying to access the "code labelled by the number 08h".
This may or may not succeed depending on what restriction the host put on the "label" 08h.
Most of the label are not accessible and they will trap, but some can work.
The same is true for `call` and `retf`.
`int` usually doesn't trap but that again depends on the OS configuration.

In general instructions that depends on the host's system structures can trap for certain values but not for other.
No harm can be done, even if the instruction turn out to execute successfully, but it cannot be executed directly in a virtualization context.

Comment: Your interpretation it's very clearly and conclusive.

You said: "int usually doesn't trap but that again depends on the OS configuration".

In a lot of cases the OS need to catch this traps for managing the system calls, unless there are other instructions that cause the transition from user to kernel mode. (What are the name of this instructions?)

If you can, you will post an example for the int ? (similar to the jmp)

Comment: @RiccardoCarbone Do you mean `syscall` (and the old `sysenter`)? The instruction `int` transfer control to an interrupt handler through an interrupt gate. So it is *exacly* like the `jmp` case. `int` don't need to trap to transfer control to the OS, it *can* trap if `int n` is executed but *n* is an interrupt vector with an invalid interrupt gate. In Intel terminology, `int` actually faults.

Comment: Ok, now i have clearly how the `int` works. About the system call management, the `syscall` is exactly what i mean. Because it avoids the interrupt overhead, there isn't any reason to use `int`, or not?

Comment: @RiccardoCarbone There is no longer any reason to use `int` as the gateway for system calls.